# How to call Elavon customer payment API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implementing Elavon payment API but in which place does `HostedPaymentData` come?

I already fetch the merchent detail API and pass the merchent detail API response in XML. Now I am trying to implement payment API see below link:

https://developer.elavonpaymentgateway.com/#!/hosted-payments/process-payment/java/html_js

See below image which place to come the `HostedPaymentData` variable.

Image reference of payment API:

[image: image reference of payment API]

TransactionController.cs

```cs
// GET: Transaction/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Transaction/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Eslopes collection)
{
    //get merchant api response and pass it xml
    //some code (get merchant api response)
       
    //now implement the customer payment api
    var hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData(); //error is Error   1   The type or namespace name 'HostedPaymentData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

}
```

This line give an error:

```
var hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData(); //error is Error   1   The type or namespace name 'HostedPaymentData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have a customer payment API:

I am doing wrong way or right way?

Comment: @Getwrong The type or namespace name 'HostedPaymentData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  give an error when I write this ```HostedPaymentData hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData();```

Comment: @Getwrong I think I missing the library which i forgot to add in my project but I don't know which library I missing?

Comment: Righto, normally directive or an assembly reference is caused from file missing

Comment: @Getwrong I am trying to find last 4 to 5 hour which library is support for hostedPaymentData varibale but not able to found

Comment: you need to provide path to the file which contains : var hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the HostedPaymentData word with the wiggly red line underneath, then clicking the lightbulb  in the line numbers margin and seeing if there is a "using ...." or "add reference to ..." suggestion in there?

Comment: @CaiusJard see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gznnu.png not display any using keyword

Comment: It's in an assembly that you have not referenced. Consult the documentation to find out what namespace this class is in

Comment: Are you using VS2019? It's much better at helping find missing refs than earlier versions- you can even write e.g. `jsonconvert` and it will offer to download newtonsoft from nuget, reference it, using it and fix the case issue.. your VS looks older, judging by the icon

Comment: @CaiusJard Are you using VS2019?  no I am using visual studio professional 2013 I am trying to find out this issue last 5 to 6 hour but not able to find the solution I searching on google

Comment: @CaiusJard when I use vs2019 then also not shown any using keyword https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4EFN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Elavon payment API it is necessary to install the **GlobalPayments.Api** NuGet package.

In the Visual Studio go to *Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...*

Select `Browse`, find **GlobalPayments.Api** NuGet package and install it.

After installing this package the Visual Studio IntelliSense will assist you to add the following namespace that including this class:

```
using GlobalPayments.Api.Entities;
```